# How to add many small windows/lights to object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm currently trying to do a Star Wars scene in blender and realized that all large spaceships/space stations have lots of tiny windows on them (which appear as lights):

[image]  (image from *Rogue One - A Star Wars Story*)

How can I replicate this effect in blender? The model I use didn't come with any texture for the lights. I've been trying to do a mix material based on a noise texture, but the result doesn't look very good:

[image]

I think the reason for the not looking good is that the lights are too dense and not rectangular. Another reason might be that some of the lights are placed too close to edges where it wouldn't be plausible for a window to be in real life.

**How can I replicate this effect in blender?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Voronoi with 0% randomness sells the effect:

[image]

You can also add some noise and texture to detect areas where you want to have lights:

[image]